# Saving the reference to a Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I am trying to develop an android application that achieves the following task:

- There is a drop-down D of different intents (Let's call them 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.)
- When button A is clicked, the application starts listening for an intent selected in D
- When button B is clicked, the application stops listening for the intent selected in D
- The sequence of starts and stops can be asynchronous, i.e. Stop 3, Start 2, Start 1, Start 2, Start 3, Stop 1 would have 2 and 3 running at the end.
- The application can be closed between when button A is clicked and button B is clicked

I am successfully able to register a broadcast receiver for a single intent, and have it receive the intent. If the application does not close, I am able to unregister the broadcast receiver. However, if the application closes, I loose my reference to the broadcast receiver, and can no longer unregister it. Is there a way to save the reference to the broadcast receiver or keep it alive even if the application closes?

Comment: Do you want to keep listening for intents after a user leaves the activities?  If so, you should use a service and hold references to your receivers in there.  Otherwise its bad practice to try and hold onto the receivers in the activity after the user leaves.

Comment: Yes, I do want to keep listening to the intents when the user leaves the activity. How would I make sure the service doesn't get killed by the OS?

Comment: You can start it as a foreground service, which displays a static notification while running, or you can use a partial `WakeLock`.  I'd recommend the first one so the user knows what your are doing and has the option to relaunch your app straight from the notification to stop or view results.